# How to query the result of another query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

I have a small problem:
i created a function with a query that joined multiple tables and the function returns the query result.
My question is: How can i query the result of that function? 
None of the solutions searched here worked for me so far.
Here's the code:

```
public  function manytomany(){
$this->db->select(*)
        ->from('tbl_users')
        ->join('tbl_users_cars','tbl_users.user_id = tbl_users_cars.user_id')
        ->join('tbl_cars','tbl_users_cars.car_id = tbl_cars.id')
        ->join('tbl_car_model','tbl_cars.car_model_id = tbl_car_model.car_model_id')
        ->order_by("user_id", "asc")
        ->group_by("user_id");
return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

How can i query the result in the same function? but outside the function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's you want, but try this :

```
public  function manytomany() {

$query = $this->db->select(*)
        ->from('tbl_users')
        ->join('tbl_users_cars','tbl_users.user_id = tbl_users_cars.user_id')
        ->join('tbl_cars','tbl_users_cars.car_id = tbl_cars.id')
        ->join('tbl_car_model','tbl_cars.car_model_id = tbl_car_model.car_model_id')
        ->order_by("user_id", "asc")
        ->group_by("user_id");

$query = $this->db->get()->result();

return $query;
}
public function otherfunction()
{
$result_query = $this->manytomany();
}
```

Comment: Remove this `$query = $this->db->get()->result();` and add this line at the end of _otherfunction_ : `$result_query = $result_query->get()->result();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public  function manytomany(){
        $this->db->select(*)
                ->from('tbl_users')
                ->join('tbl_users_cars','tbl_users.user_id = tbl_users_cars.user_id')
                ->join('tbl_cars','tbl_users_cars.car_id = tbl_cars.id')
                ->join('tbl_car_model','tbl_cars.car_model_id = tbl_car_model.car_model_id')
                ->order_by("user_id", "asc")
                ->group_by("user_id");
        $sql = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ($sql) as table WHERE ...');
    ...
    }
```